# How to launch my app via NFC tag?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, nfc, windows-10, uwp

I'm currently working on porting an app to UWP. The app has a page with a "Write to NFC" button. After the user taps it, it waits for an NFC tag and writes a `LaunchApp:WriteTag` binary message.

What worked fine under WP8.1, doesn't work at all under Windows 10 UWP:

```
var proximityDevice = Windows.Networking.Proximity.ProximityDevice.GetDefault();

if (proximityDevice != null)
{
    var launchArgs = "user=default";

    var appId = "App";
    var appName = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.Id.FamilyName + "!" + appId;

    var launchAppMessage = launchArgs + "\tWindows\t" + appName;

    var dataWriter = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter();
    dataWriter.UnicodeEncoding = Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf16LE;
    dataWriter.WriteString(launchAppMessage);
    var launchAppPubId = proximityDevice.PublishBinaryMessage("LaunchApp:WriteTag", dataWriter.DetachBuffer());
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. The NFC capability is enabled and the WP8.1 app works on the same phone, so this shouldn't be an issue.

I already tried multiple formats as the problem seems to be the `launchAppMessage`, where I didn't find a UWP doc for. There's a [Windows 8+](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/hh701129.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-3) MSDN article, which describes the string to be in the format:

```
myArgs\tWindows\tAppFamilyName!App
```

What I tried:

1. `myArgs` is short enough - shouldn't be a problem.
2. `Windows` or `WindowsPhone` doesn't make any difference. Both don't work.
3. `AppFamilyName` is the correct app family name that's inside my app manifest. The app is associated to the store and it looks like this shouldn't be the problem as well.
4. `App` is what's inside `<Application id="App" ... />` in my app manifest. Trying `MyAppNamespace.App` didn't work as well and calling `CurrentApp.AppId` (what's used in WinRT apps) throws an exception.

By "not working" I mean that it writes to the tag, but the tag is not recognized by Windows 10 at all.

One more thing I found, is that for `myArgs\tWindows\tAppFamilyName!App` the app throws the following exception - without any further details:

```
System.ExecutionEngineException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in Unknown Module.
```

I really hope someone has an idea on how to solve this. Unfortunately there are no UWP samples for this yet and the docs are still the old ones... :/

PS: using a custom protocol together with `WindowsUri:WriteTag` works fine but I want only my app to open with the NFC tag. Also, the confirmation dialog then looks like "Do you want to open the app associated with mycustomprotocol?" - which looks not very user friendly. So that's no real solution for me, more a workaround I don't want to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Windows 10 Mobile UWP**

If you are only targeting Windows 10 Mobile, the 8.1 way still works, given that you get the right App ID. It can be retrieved through:

```cs
Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp.AppId
```

However, that only works when the app is installed through the store, as the ID is assigned during store association / publishing. In developer deployed builds, the API will crash through with "Exception from HRESULT: 0x803F6107".

The resulting LaunchApp record then needs the platform "WindowsPhone" and that app ID. The following code creates a LaunchApp tag through the open source NFC / NDEF library (https://github.com/andijakl/ndef-nfc) and works on Windows 10 Mobile - both for writing the tag and for launching the app. Again - given it has been published & installed through the store:

```cs
var record = new NdefLaunchAppRecord { Arguments = "Hello World" };
var appId = Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp.AppId;    // Note: crashes when app is not installed through app store!
record.AddPlatformAppId("WindowsPhone", appId);
var message = new NdefMessage { record };
proximityDevice.PublishBinaryMessage("NDEF:WriteTag", msgArray.AsBuffer(), MessageWrittenHandler);
```

**Windows 10 PC**

Unfortunately, things are different for PCs. The method above does not work there, neither does the documented method for Windows 8.1.

The closest I could get so far is to get Windows 10 to recognize the LaunchApp tag and to open the store on the correct page. But Windows / the store does not realize that the app is already installed and therefore does not open it.

This is the code, again using the NFC / NDEF library:

```cs
var record = new NdefLaunchAppRecord { Arguments = "Hello World" };
var familyName = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.Id.FamilyName;
var appId = Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp.AppId;    // Note: crashes when app is not installed through app store!
record.AddPlatformAppId("Windows", "{" + familyName + "!" + appId + "}");
var message = new NdefMessage { record };
proximityDevice.PublishBinaryMessage("NDEF:WriteTag", msgArray.AsBuffer(), MessageWrittenHandler);
```

Of course, you can also combine the two platform IDs to a single NFC tag, given that you have enough writable memory, as those app IDs are huge.

Comment: Thanks Andreas! I already saw the link to my SO question in your code, so thanks for the detailed answer :) I think the real problem here is the exception which is thrown if the app is not installed through the store, so let's see if MS can do something about this as [someone from the NFC team of MSFT answered in my MSDN forum thread about this problem](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b1e2743c-1cb3-4129-ade9-f8774d13ae0e/uwp-how-to-directly-launch-my-app-via-nfc-tag?forum=wpdevelop).

Comment: Great to see that, thanks for the link! I'm also following up through our MVP mailing list - let's keep the SO posting updated when we get a definitive answer from MS!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way :

1. Register a background task and using a NFC trigger
2. Register your app for uri activation.
3. Program the backgroundtask to activate when tapped with a NFC tag and then launch the app suing URI schemes

   // Set the recommended app

   ```
   var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
   options.PreferredApplicationPackageFamilyName= "Contoso.URIApp_8wknc82po1e";
   options.PreferredApplicationDisplayName = "Contoso URI Ap";

   // Launch the URI and pass in the recommended app 
   // in case the user has no apps installed to handle the URI
   var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uriContoso, options);
   ```

Comment: May I ask what a "NFC trigger" should be? I can't find any `IBackgroundTaskTrigger` which triggers when NFC tags are found?

Comment: As you answered several other questions in the meantime I guess you have no idea about your "answer" here as well... too bad. :/ I hope others can help.

Comment: I was trying to find a solution. I came over this trigger of sensordatathreshold trigger but unfortunately i dont have a NFC enabled WIndows device to test or experiment this .. so i cant help you further at this point .. There is a hard way but i it's not worth the pain .. it is building custom triggers.. I think it is not accessible to common devs .. if u want to take a lokk go to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn705812(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: may be you can try researching on lowlevel apis and getting the dll and creating a c# wrapper around it and use it as a trigger.. just theory .. not tested ..

Answer (score 0):

If you have a WP8.1 app and running this app on Windows Phone 10 and want to write NFC tags on your phone you have to retrieve the `AppId`. This is done by opening the [Windows Dev Center](https://developer.microsoft.com/dashboard?from=UHF) open the corresponding app, click `App Management` and then `App identity`. Then under the point `URL for Windows Phone 8.1 and earlier` copy the `GUID` and replace `Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp.AppId`