# Launching a specific app installed on Windows 10 Mobile using its family package name

Tags: uwp

I want to launch a specific app using only its family package name without any Launcher URI scheme.

I tried using Launcher class but I don't know the URI protocols of the app I want to launch. It may happen that the app I want to launch does not have any launcher Uri associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

Family-Package names are private and aren't accessible to everyone.

All you can do is Launch uri specific to some content or a file format :

In this [How to launch my app via NFC tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34221812/how-to-launch-my-app-via-nfc-tag/34436970#34436970) i've discussed a way to reegister ur own uri .. so if any app on the platform registers itself with the format .. u can launch them ..

This post shows how to open up an fb app :

[How can I open the Facebook App for sharing a link on WP8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351400/how-can-i-open-the-facebook-app-for-sharing-a-link-on-wp8)

It works if you try and match .. i had an app that opened whatsapp in wp8.1

I used **await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("whatsapp:"));**

well if you are trying to open apps of a specific file format like PDF then there is seperate uri scheme to it .. MSDN has great documentation on it ..

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt228340.aspx

Comment: The problem is not with the family package names. I can get them for all the apps installed. The problem is with the Uri. I want to launch those apps using only family package name OR get a list of launcher Uri associated with those apps.

Comment: Unfortunately thee is no way to do this presently !!